# How to read .tfrecord files into R?

Tags: r, tensorflow

Is it possible to read TensorFlow's .tfrecord files into R?

I suppose it should look something like this:

```
library(tensorflow)
sess <- tf$InteractiveSession()
TFdata <- tf$TFRecordReader(...)
```

But I am not sure what the arguments `...` should be and whether I am even close.

**Edit:**

I managed to get this far:

```
filename <- "file.tfrecord"
records <- iterate(tf$python_io$tf_record_iterator(filename))
```

`records` is a list of the correct size I expected but I am not familiar with the class of the elements in the list:

```
class(records[[1]])
```

[1] "python.builtin.str"        "python.builtin.basestring" "python.builtin.object"

I might have to make use of the functions in the reticulate R package. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have `tensorflow` in R available. Though, from the Python API there should go `name=...` and optional `TFRecordOptions` class with `compression_type`.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed. It still doesn't help me to get the .tfrecord files into the  R session.

Comment: I am considering reading the data into Python and then exporting it to csv files for R to read. But I will probably run into memory problems since these files are extremely big.